# Where is Haskell's or GHC's main defined?

Tags: haskell, language-lawyer, standards, program-entry-point

In Haskell, the execution of a compiled program starts with executing `main` in module `Main`. This function must be of type `IO ()`.

Which standard or reference defines the above?

[Haskell 2010](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch1.html#x6-90001) and [Haskell 98](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/intro.html) don't define `main` formally (although there are several examples of functions called `main`), instead saying:

> We leave as implementation dependent the ways in which Haskell programs are to be manipulated, interpreted, compiled, etc.

[GHC User's Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using.html) instructs the user to create a `main` function but never mentions its required type or that it is the start of the program execution. There are references to the `Main` module but not `main` function.

Compare [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) (references C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup (p: 13)):

> Every C program [...] contains the definition [...] of a function called main, which is the designated **start of the program**.

Which standard or reference says that `main` is the start of execution of a Haskell program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A Haskell *program* is a collection of modules, one of which, by convention, must be called `Main` and must export the value `main`. The *value* of the program is the value of the identifier `main` in module `Main`, which must be a computation of type `IO τ` for some type `τ` (see Chapter [7](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch7.html#x14-1420007)). When the program is executed, the computation `main` is performed, and its result (of type `τ`) is discarded.

https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#dx11-98001